# bash - what is the best way to improve the performance of this code

Tags: performance, bash, refactoring

I have now got my script working, I used cdwn and so long as there are no files and only one directory in the current working directory, it cd's to it. Otherwise it breaks an infinite loop. I have several generic functions that I have created for this script, but will use for others, and I use several find commands and an egrep. Please advise on making this more performant, this has mainly been an exercise in reviewing and learning bash stuff, but I would like to make use of it.

The following function is used to check if there exist any files in the wd.

```
function checkForFilesInCurrentDir(){
    # check if there are files in the current directory
    doFilesExist=`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f`
    if [ -z "$doFilesExist" ]; then
    #   echo "no files"
        return 0 
    else
    #   echo "some files"
        return 1
    fi
}
```

The following function checks for dirs, then prints the string on seperate lines, then uses egrep to count the number of lines on which that pattern occurs, effectively counting the number of directories in the wd.

```
function numOfDirsInWD(){
    # check number of dirs in working directory and return that num
    checkForDirs=`find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d`
    numOfDirs=$(echo "$checkForDirs" | egrep -c "./")
    return $numOfDirs
}
```

The following function is the script itself. It opens an infinite loop, check for files and if they are detected it breaks, then it checks how many dirs are in the wd and if there are more or less than 1 it breaks out of the loop. otherwise it does an ls and cd's to the sole dir. Then repeats on the next dir. to go up

```
function cdwn (){
    while :
    do
        # check for files
        checkForFilesInCurrentDir
        filesExist="$?"
        if [[ filesExist -eq 1 ]]; then
            echo "files exist"
            break
        fi

        # check that only one dir
        numOfDirsInWD
        numOfDirs="$?"
        if [[ numOfDirs -eq 1 ]]; then
            # cd to it
            echo "only one dir"
            name=`ls`
            cd "$name"
        else
            # break out of the loop
            echo "there is not a sole dir"
            break
        fi
    done
}
```

On my current crappy computer, it takes about 18 seconds to go down about ten empty directories... the main delay seems to be at the start. I will check for responses in the morning, got carried away with this stuff and its now 6am where I am... help is appreciated.

Comment: On a side note, you can use `inline code` by using backticks: `, for that, enclose your code in said backticks.

Comment: I dont follow, what do you mean?

Comment: Nothing I thought you tried to embed code in your text but it was a formatting issue which was solved by that other guy, so no worries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, get the number of files like this:

```
function numOfDirsInWD(){
    # check number of dirs in working directory and return that num
    checkForDirs=`find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d`
    return ${checkForDirs[#]}
}
```

which will be considerably faster and easier.

Secondly, you forgot a dollar sign. Replace yours with this line:

```
if [[ $numOfDirs -eq 1 ]]; then
```

Post if you experience further issues.

You can also immediately change directory using this code:

```
cd $(ls)
```

That is if there is only one dir.

As to why you are stuck in an infinite loop: you keep going if there is more than one file in the dir. check if number of files is `ge 1` and break accordingly. So change this line: `if [[ filesExist -eq 1 ]]; then` to `if [[ filesExist -ge 1 ]]; then`

Comment: I don't follow the first bit, is checkForDirs an in built command? I typed the code you put there into my git bash terminal and it didnt work.

Ah, my bad! I added the dollar signs and its quicker, but now when it reaches the end it returns < followed by a whole lot of special characters that appear to look like smiley faces....

Comment: No it's not a command, it's a variable to which you assign the size of the array `checkForDirs`. You're supposed to change the lines of code in your script by these lines.

Comment: @user122072 Is this on Windows? On my Linux system it takes 0.06 seconds to descend into 10 dirs.

Comment: @thatotherguy Haha, valid question, probably should have started off with that.

Comment: Oh, my bad! I have followed your cd advice, only used cd "$(ls" as that fixes the problem with dirs using spaces, which is important since i'm on windows. And after fixing the missing $ in two locations, its now pretty quick. I haven't used your array for the num of dirs, but I am now satisfied with the script! Thanks for your help now, and earlier! now I have no excuses not to go to bed. almost 7am... thanks for your help!  I will mark this answered and vote it up

Comment: I know the feeling, almost 8 am here. Glad to help btw!

Comment: I thought I was the only one! Good morning and good night  : )